# Find keyword and scrape text from same field to convert to date

Tags: excel, parsing, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to work out how to create an Excel function that will find a keyword in any row within a defined column, and then will scrape text in the same field (in dd/mm/yy format), converting it to date in a new column.

Example of field data ['Keyword' , 13/10/17]

Is this possible in Excel? would VBA be needed?

Thanks

Comment: Will there be multiple matches?

Comment: Hi, no just looking for a single keyword. I of course understand how to do this, but not sure on the VBA that would be used to then convert the text to a date in a new row. Ultimate idea is to then use that date for a pivot table.

Comment: Added an answer using a datafield array instead of pure (slow) range loops to help other users reading this question . Welcome at SO, but consider the next time, that you are expected to make some *minimal coding efforts* by your own when asking here.

Comment: I've overseen that you are parsing your column text consisting of 2 portions instead of getting the date string from another column. Hold on for my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Example using a datafield array:**

Always declare your variables using the `Option Explicit` expression in the declaration head of your code module. The procedure code shows you a fast method using a data field array instead of looping through a range. You can easily set range values to a variant array by this example code:

```
Dim a         ' variant
a = ThisWorkbook.Range("A2:A4711").value
```

By that way you can speed up your search. Keep in mind that VBA then creates automatically a one based array with Dimension 2.

**What does the below procedure?**

- searches for "Keyword" in col A,
- gets string ("13/10/17") of col B, convert to date and
- writes date to col C in sheet Test

**Test Call**

```
Option Explicit
```

' Note: write Option Explicit into your code module's declaration head

```
Sub TestCall()
' Example
  writeKeyDate "Keyword", "A", "B", "C", "Test"
End Sub
```

**Procedure code**

```
Sub writeKeyDate(ByVal sKey As String, _
                 ByVal sCol As String, ByVal sCol2 As String, ByVal sCol3 As String, _
                 Optional ByVal wsName As String = "Test")
'     sKey .... search string
'     sCol .... character of column where to search
'     sCol2 ... character of column with datestring
'     sCol3 ... character of target column
'     wsName .. worksheet name as string, e.g. "MySheet", or "Test"
'               (if not set, then automatically "Test")
' declare vars
  Dim oSht    As Worksheet                       ' work sheet
  Dim a       As Variant                         ' one based 2-dim data field array
  Dim i       As Long                            ' rows
  Dim n       As Long                            ' last row
  Dim sDate   As String                          ' date string in sCol2
' set sheet
  Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)     ' fully qualified reference to worksheet
' get last row number of search column
  n = oSht.Range(sCol & oSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  If n < 2 Then Exit Sub                         ' only if data avaible (row 1 assumed as head line)

' get range values to one based 2dim data field array
  a = oSht.Range(sCol & "2:" & sCol & n).Value    '  array gets data from e.g. "A2:A100"
' loop through column sCol to find keyword sKey
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)              '  array boundaries counting from 1 to n -1 (one off for title line)
      ' searchstring found
        If LCase(a(i, 1)) = LCase(sKey) Then  '  case insensitive
           sDate = oSht.Range(sCol2 & i + 1).Value2
           On Error Resume Next
           If Len(Trim(sDate)) > 0 Then
              oSht.Range(sCol3 & i + 1).Value = CDate(sDate)
           End If
        End If
  Next

End Sub
```

**Note**

- a) I assume you have a title line in row 1.
- b) The procedure writes back any code finding (case insensitive); if you have unique keys only you could include a `Exit For`in the last `If`condition:

  ```
     If Len(Trim(sDate)) > 0 Then
        oSht.Range(sCol3 & i + 1).Value = CDate(sDate)
     '  >>>> possible insert, if unique keys only >>>>
        Exit For
     End If
  ```
- c) If you want the search case sensitive you have to change code as follows:

  `If a(i, 1) = sKey` instead of `If LCase(a(i, 1)) = LCase(sKey)`

Good luck.

============================================

**EDIT example for search and data within cell in same column (colon separated)**

```
Sub TestCall1()
' Example
  writeKeyDate1 "Keyword", "A", "B", "Test"
End Sub
```

**Edited procedure for search in ONE column**

```
Sub writeKeyDate1(ByVal skey As String, _
                 ByVal sCol As String, ByVal sCol2 As String, _
                 Optional ByVal wsName As String = "Test")
'     sKey .... search string
'     sCol .... character of column where to search (includes key, date string)
'     sCol2 ... character of target column
'     wsName .. worksheet name as string, e.g. "MySheet", or "Test"
'               (if not set, then automatically "Test")
' declare vars
  Dim oSht    As Worksheet                       ' work sheet
  Dim a       As Variant                         ' one based 2-dim data field array
  Dim i       As Long                            ' rows
  Dim n       As Long                            ' last row
  Dim s       As String
  Dim sDate   As String                          ' date string in sCol2
' set sheet
  Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)     ' fully qualified reference to worksheet
' get last row number of search column
  n = oSht.Range(sCol & oSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  If n < 2 Then Exit Sub                         ' only if data avaible (row 1 assumed as head line)

' get range values to one based 2dim data field array
  a = oSht.Range(sCol & "2:" & sCol & n).Value    '  array gets data from e.g. "A2:A100"
' loop through column sCol to find keyword sKey
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)              '  array boundaries counting from 1 to n -1 (one off for title line)
        s = Split(LCase(a(i, 1)) & "", ",")(0)
      ' searchstring found
        If InStr(LCase(s), LCase(skey)) > 0 Then
           sDate = Trim(Split(LCase(a(i, 1)) & ",", ",")(1))
           On Error Resume Next
           If Len(sDate) > 0 Then
              oSht.Range(sCol2 & i + 1).Value = CDate(sDate)
           End If
        End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is brilliant. What if the date and keyword are in the same field though? Separated by a comma e.g. Keyword, 13/10/2017

Comment: Added procedure 'writeKeyDate1` allowing parsing of keyword and date within the same column cell.

Comment: @SDROB, did my edit as of Nov solve your additional question in the comment so that you could mark your OP as accepted?